# port management in python/flask application

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am writing a REST API using the micro framework Flask with python programming language. In the debug mode the application detect any change in source code and restart itself using the same host and port. In the production mode (no debug) the application does not restart it self when changing the source code so I have to restart the application by my self; the problem in this case is that the application cannot run using a port previously used in an old version the application, so I am asked to change the port with every app update:

This is how my code look like:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import json
import os

app = Flask(__name__) 


@app.route('/method1', methods=['GET'])
def method1():
    return jsonify({"result":"true"})

@app.route('/method2', methods=['GET'])
def method2():
    return jsonify({"result":"true"})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=15000)
```

How to solve this issue? or do I have to change port with every application update?

Comment: Probably you're running an HTTP server  like Gunicorn on production. See what is running on the same port.( you can use command `lsof -i TCP:15000`. Even if you're not using Gunicorn, still you can get the PID of the instance using the specific port. ) If it is still active, you should kill it before you run it again.  Gunicorn has options to restart on file change, but I wouldn't recommend on production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code `test.py` doesn't change port that's specified in `.run()` args:

```
from flask import Flask    

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "123"

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080) # or host=127.0.0.1, depends on your needs
```

There is nothing that can force flask to bind to another TCP port in allowed range if you specified the desired port in `run` function. If this port is already used by another app - you will see 
`OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use` 
after launching.

***UPD***: This is output from my pc if I run this code several time using `python test.py` command:

```
artem@artem:~/Development/$ python test.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
^Cartem@artem:~/Development$ python test.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
^Cartem@artem:~/Development/$ python test.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
^Cartem@artem:~/Development/$ python test.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2017 17:04:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

As you can see flask gets binded to 8080 port every time.

***UPD2***: when you will setup production env for your service - you won't need to take care of ports in flask code - you will just need to specify desired port in web server config that will work with your scripts through [wsgi layer](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/).

Comment: it's almost the same as my code, what can make the difference ?

Comment: yes, there is no difference, because if you run this code using for example `python main.py` - you get binded to 8080 TCP port every time you run this code. there is nothing that can force flask to bind to another port (in allowed range obviously)

Comment: just as you mentioned; `python myApp.py`

Comment: can you copy my code, and perform all that I did (see UPD) and send output ?

Comment: solved! I had problem with a port already used in another application.

Comment: Good. In this case you should see `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use` error.