# I wrote a small web code using Flask and I entered http://127.0.0.1:5000/ in the browser but it is running some other code How to solve this?

Tags: python, flask, html

I wrote a small code for web page using Flask and I entered http://127.0.0.1:5000/ in the browser but it is running some other code but not mine How to solve this?

Comment: How can people help you without knowing anything about your code, your flask setup, your network, or the code that's actually running?

Comment: Have you tried `localhost:5000` instead?

Comment: what code are you running? what is your expected output? what are you seeing in browser? what do you see in your console after starting your flask app?

Answer (score 0):

Configure flask to use another local port or configure the app running on port 5000 to use another port.

You can read more about configuring flask ports here: [port management in python/flask application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393479/port-management-in-python-flask-application).